pyproject.toml - dynamic versioning from file
With pyproject.toml is it possible to set the version from a file in the module at runtime?
Ex ranchercli/ranchercli.py (comes from a git commit hook doing dynamic versioning):
__VERSION__ = open("VERSION.TXT", "r").read().strip()

works fine in the module:
>>> import ranchercli.ranchercli
>>> ranchercli.ranchercli.__VERSION__ 
'0.14.1'

In pyproject.toml:
[project]
name = "ranchercli"
dynamic = ["version"]
:
[tool.setuptools.dynamic]
version = {attr = "ranchercli.ranchercli.__VERSION__"}

But when I try pip install -e . or any other pip:
File "C:\Users\mobj\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-8129o6il\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\config\expand.py", line 75, in __getattr__
  raise AttributeError(f"{self.name} has no attribute {attr}") from e
      AttributeError: ranchercli.ranchercli has no attribute __VERSION__


A tool like setuptools-scm can "extract Python package versions from git or hg metadata instead of declaring them as the version argument or in an SCM managed file."

Dynamic versioning works differently on different build backends. Judging by [tool.setuptools.dynamic], you're using setuptools.
For setuptools, there is an easier way to get the version from a file:
[tool.setuptools.dynamic]
version = {file = "VERSION.TXT"}

Nevertheless, if you really want to get the version from a module attribute, check your project structure. Provide the directory tree, the Python version and the full pyproject.toml, so we can reproduce the error and debug what is wrong.
